# i want select one checkbox from 3 checkbox and display div if none is seletced hide div in simple javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am able to select any one checkbox but i am displaying div more time as i select checkbox
here is the check box:

```
<INPUT type=CHECKBOX id='IP_3820' IP='12.12.12.12' PORT='5060' onclick='javascript: ipSelected(this)' value='3820' >12.12.12.12
<br />
<INPUT type=CHECKBOX id='IP_3822' IP='12.12.12.13' PORT='5060' onclick='javascript: ipSelected(this)' value='3822' >12.12.12.13
```

This div i want to display as check any one checkbox:

```
<div id='vp_3822' style='float:right;display:none;'>
    <input type='radio' name='3822' id='IP_none' value='none' /> NONE / 
    <input type='radio' name='3822' id='g729' value='g729'  />g729/ 
    <input type='radio' name='3822' id='ulaw' value='ulaw' checked='checked' />ulaw
</div><br />
```

This is the function:

```
function ipSelected(el){
    if(el.checked){
        document.getElementById("IP_none").checked=false;
        if(last_ip_id!="" && last_ip_id!=el.id && ( document.getElementById('system').value=='voipswitch' || document.getElementById('system').value=='asterisk' || document.getElementById('system').value=='ipsmarx')){
            try { document.getElementById(last_ip_id).checked=false;}catch(e){}
        }
        last_ip_id = el.id;
        document.getElementById("vp_" + el.value).style.display="block";
        // Set destination value
        if((document.getElementById('system').value=='voipswitch') || (document.getElementById('system').value=='asterisk' || document.getElementById('system').value=='ipsmarx')){
            document.getElementById('dest_span').innerHTML = "@" + el.getAttribute("IP") + ":" + el.getAttribute("PORT");
            document.theForm.idiplist.value = el.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you keep displaying the divs on each checkbox's check but have forgotten to hide the rest of the divs

add a class all the divs say `divClass`

then use the below code to display the correct div and keep the others hidden

```
$(".divClass").hide();
$("#vp_"+el.value).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide Div in javascript

```
document.getElementById('"#vp_"+el.value').style.display = 'none';
```

Show Div in javascript

```
 document.getElementById('"#vp_"+el.value').style.display = 'block';
```